# How can I populate a combobox with a list of outlook calendar folders that are available to me?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, outlook

I want to get a list of all of the calendars (folders) in my outlook and put them into a combo box.  I have a top level Idea of how to do it, but I don't know enough about the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook; to get the data.  I'm sure it will be some kind of a for each combobox1.Items.add(Calendar);

Full disclosure:  It is my plan to write a form application that will have a combobox to select the folder, another to select the items, and then populate the form from the item selected.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application oApp = null;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.NameSpace mapiNamespace = null;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MAPIFolder CalendarFolder = null;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Items outlookCalendarItems = null;

        oApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
        //mapiNamespace = oApp.GetNamespace("MAPI"); ;
        //CalendarFolder = mapiNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar);
        CalendarFolder = mapiNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar);
        outlookCalendarItems = CalendarFolder.Items;
        outlookCalendarItems.IncludeRecurrences = true;

        foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MAPIFolder item in CalendarFolder)
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: Apparently I can't enumerate a MAPIFolder object... :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get all sub-folders of the Calendar folder, use:

```
var oApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
var mapiNamespace = oApp.GetNamespace("MAPI");
var calendarFolder = mapiNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar);

foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MAPIFolder folder in calendarFolder.Folders)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{folder.Name}");
}
```

Tested with Outlook 2013 and 2016:

[image: Outlook sub-calendar]

Prints

> Cal1

Comment: I took your code as is and dropped it into a button_Click.  Did a cobobox.items.add(folder) no luck.  stuck a counter into the for each it didn't increment. then created a label and had it write to the label as the first task in the for each loop.  It never wrote to the label.  so it looks like it is not going into the foreach loop.

Comment: Does your Calendar have any sub-folders?

Comment: yes it does...  So the calendar that I specifically want to read from is a shared calendar.

Comment: Interesting…  I am using 2016.  I wonder if the interop is deprecated....

Comment: Tested now also with Outlook 2016 - works fine, too.

Comment: Klaus, thank you for all your help.  I am at a loss here..  I don't know why it isn't working on my end.  I am using windows 10 visual studio 2017.   I added the reference for Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook ver 9.6.0.0.   I am kind of new to c# but I believe my syntax is correct.

Comment: I have made an interesting discovery.  When I run the solution in the IDE it fails, but when I build the project and run the exe it works...